# DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info

Tags: aws-amplify

I was trying to deploy in AWS amplify and encountered this error.

I'm just starting on learning AWS amplify
[image]

I'm really struggling to navigate the AWS console. A little bit of a guide in that will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

If you installed a template like sanity or any other, the name property in the package.json of that template would be clashing with the name property in your main directory's package .json i.e

> project-dir/package.json
> project-dir/sanity/package.json

To clear the error, change the name in the template's package.json so they don't clash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update for the thread. Having discovered that react-native init doesn't support the current node.js (12.13.0 as of this writing on 11/16/2019). I un-installed Node.JS and installed 12.10.0 and managed to get the files built using react-native init MyAwesomeProject --template typescript.
Then I read through these comments and realized that the "name" property in the template folder will be whatever you called your project when you created it. I tried a new folder with a different name and sure enough, the name matched and I got the "Duplicated files or mocks" message.
I cleaned the build and then I changed the name in the template folder's copy of package.json to a different name.
After rebuilding the app started working. I'm not sure if this is creating duplicate instances with different names in the app. I'll try to remember to come back here if this becomes a problem.

copied and past https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25796

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).